# Blender 2.8 - all non-rendering objects gone from viewport but still exist

Tags: 3d-view

I remember there was an option in pre-2.8 for "only render" option to display but where is it in Blender 2.8+.  I must have hit some terrible hotkey something.

All object such as camera, fields, empties are all invisible in viewport.

Anyone know what hotkey or checkbox that controls this?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your post (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add an image (a screen capture) of your interface. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Answer (score 1):

Did you unselect the Show Overlays button

[image]